# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Pivoting a table using a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012, I get the error. I have provided the stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Report_SalesJournal]  
     (@fromDate DATETIME,  
      @toDate DATETIME,
      @locationId INT) 
AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(AccountName) + ',' 
    FROM 
        (SELECT DISTCINT AccountName 
         FROM vw_SalesJournal 
        ) AS tmp

    SELECT @cols = SUBSTRING(@cols, 0, LEN(@cols)) 

    SET @query = 
'SELECT * from 
(
    select InvoiceDate, TransactionNumber, CustomerName,  Amount,  AccountName from vw_SalesJournal Where (InvoiceDate BETWEEN convert(date,' +  @fromDate + ',105) AND convert(date,' + @toDate + ',105)) OR LocationId=' + @locationId + '
) src
pivot 
(
    max(Amount) for AccountName in (' + @cols + ')
) piv'
```

I have already gone through and also tried some of the answers provided on similar post.

Comment: If you want to chop off the time portion, simply use `CAST(@fromDate AS DATE)`

Comment: Please do debug your code to the actual line giving you trouble and edit your question to [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will learn more yourself and you would get better and faster answers.

Comment: Seems like you have not posted the query as-is. There is a typo (`DISTCINT`) and you were probably converting to `VARCHAR` instead of `DATE` (the code would work with DATE).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Comment: @All I did not post this question because I won't be able to debug it. I posted it because i needed fresh eyes to look at it, maybe see what I could not.

Comment: @marc_s I really appreciate your advice. From henceforth, I will exclude `sp_`

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert your date to string (with format YYYYMMDD) and enclose the date string in single quote before concatenate

```
BETWEEN ''' + convert(varchar(10), @fromDate, 121) + ''' AND
```